# Css printing of Forms

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to CSS/JS. I have created letter type form where Input Fileds are surrounded by Contents. The print of the form is not looking good becoz if the use input less text in the input box, white space after the text is appearing, If the User types more text, only the area which is appearing on the screen is getting printed. Though i have used document.write and CSS methods i am not getting solution. Pls help me out
regards
ravi

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate CSS file that defines your print-only CSS and then include it using the `media="print"` property. By doing this, you can make your page print differently than it looks on screen, hide elements, adjust width, etc.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="foo.css">
```